# Passing Argument to Pytest py.test . Global argument for all test

Tags: python, pytest

I want to pass argument to the my test using py.Test.

Note : This argument will be global across test. 
Please suggest how to do that.

Comment: Please suggest what you have tried

Comment: I really don't get what you're trying to ask.

Comment: When I am giving like this  $ py.test -m 'test_test1'  --stringinput="hello"  it is throwing an error unrecognized arguments: --stringinput=hello . I basically wants to pass custom parameter to my py.test

Answer (score 9):

Check [this](https://pytest.org/latest/example/simple.html#control-skipping-of-tests-according-to-command-line-option) manaual. You should define your argument by using `parser.addoption` method in hook `pytest_addoption`, at file `conftest.py`. Then you can get value of your argument by checking `request.config.getoption` method:

```
# /home/user/conftest.py
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--stringvalue', action='store', dest='stringvalue')

# /home/user/test_first.py
def test_test1(request):
    assert 'checkme' == request.config.getoption('stringvalue')

$ py.test /home/user/test_first.py --stringvalue checkme
```